# Kernel-panic after swtiching from uClibc to glibc

Tags: kernel

I have a working buildroot environment based upon uClibc. I need to switch to glibc in order to add the bluez5 package. After rebuild all on boot I get a kernel-panic error:

```
not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000004
```

The other configuration settings are the same.
I guess it's related to glibc...is there any trick to run glibc on RPi3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I guess it's related to glibc...

I guess that depends in what sense you mean "related".  Related to *your use* of it, perhaps.

More directly, it is from the linux kernel; the "Attempted to kill init!" error message can be found in the source tree (see `kernel/exit.c`), as can the forward trace (i.e., from a subsequent call) "not syncing" (`kernel/panic.c`).

Unravelling that would require further poking around.  I think a common cause of this in a normal context is a problem with the root filesystem.  I can say that I do not think "the problem" is simply that it cannot be found or read, unless perhaps you are using an initramfs (which n.b., is probably pointless on a platform specific kernel; this is why they are not normally used on the pi at all).  These are crude guesses though.

You are probably going to have to do some tedious debugging, more specifically, tracing the execution of the kernel to find out where it goes wrong.  Hopefully you have two pis because being able to do this in contrast to your uClibc version might be helpful.

> is there any trick to run glibc on RPi3?

Not in particular, since glibc is the basis of Raspbian and all of the other normative Pi oriented distros (as far as I aware).  Prior to jessie, Debian/Raspbian actually used a slight variant, [eglibc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_GLIBC), but since that was merged back into glibc several years ago and is no longer developed, Debian 8 (jessie) marks a return to glibc proper.

Comment: With "related" I mean the same configuration is working with uClibc but not with glibc. And, no, I'm not using initramfs. Unfortunately, I have not enough knowledge to debug the execution of the kernel.

Comment: I'm not a buildroot (or uClibc) user so I'm not much help, but I will give you a bit of advice: Your question is so vague and devoid of information, on a relatively obscure topic, that you will probably never get any other answer to this question here (but good luck, I could be wrong).   You might want to inquire on [buildroot's IRC or mail list](https://buildroot.org/support.html) about how to use glibc properly, if re-scanning the documentation etc. does not get you anywhere.  I doubt very much the pi really has anything to do with the problem.

Comment: I agree. I've just informed the buildroot mailing list about this issue. The question is so vague because I don't know what information might help! I also would post the screenshot of the kernel-panic but it seems I can't here.